# How to insert Data into MySql Database from Two HTML Forms/SubForms

Tags: java, html, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have 2 HTML Forms:
1. Register/Login
2. After User gets Login, He used to update details of him.

I used MySql database in order to save Login details of User. And also i have another table for updating details of him after his login.

I got succeed in register/Login process., But problem arises here.,., I dont know how to proceed further., After his Login., the user should be able to update his details in his respective table.

Here is My Login Servlet which takes information from First Main Login Form After User gets Login., Then there is another HTML Form where user enter his personal details., which is stored in another table., There Problem arises., I'm unable to process details of User in second table

Login Servlet:

```
package com.ea.servlet;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String name = request.getParameter("name");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
String mem = request.getParameter("mem");
try{

 //loading drivers for mysql
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

 //creating connection with the database 
  Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
             ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EATWO","root","");

Statement statement = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from singer where name='" + name + "'");
String duplicate = null;
while(rs.next()){
    duplicate = rs.getString(1);
    }
if(duplicate == null){
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
            ("insert into Singer(name,password,member) values(?,?,?)");
     ps.setString(1, name);
     ps.setString(2, pass);
     ps.setString(3, mem);
     int i=ps.executeUpdate();

       if(i>0)
       {
         out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
       }
    }
    else{
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.html").forward(request, response);
        //request.setAttribute("error","Invalid Username/password");
               request.getRequestDispatcher("/register_err.html").forward(request, response);
    }
}
catch(Exception se)
{
    se.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

This code is the effected one to say...I want this servelt to get corrected according to your suggestions..Here is the Second SubForm., Where after User gets login., This code helps user to store his personal details., But i got stuck with this.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*; 
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String name = request.getParameter("name");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
String mem = request.getParameter("mem");
try{

//loading drivers for mysql
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//creating connection with the database 
  Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
             ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EATWO","root","");

Statement statement = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from singer where name='" + name + "'");
String duplicate = null;
while(rs.next()){
    duplicate = rs.getString(1);
    }
if(duplicate == null){
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
            ("insert into Singer(name,password,member) values(?,?,?)");
     ps.setString(1, name);
     ps.setString(2, pass);
     ps.setString(3, mem);
     int i=ps.executeUpdate();

       if(i>0)
       {
         out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
       }
    }
    else{
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.html").forward(request, response);
        //request.setAttribute("error","Invalid Username/password");
               request.getRequestDispatcher("/register_err.html").forward(request, response);
    }
}
catch(Exception se)
{
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have done so far.

Comment: yes. show some codes.

Comment: Waiting for your suggestions !!!!

Comment: Just to be sure if I get it right: you want to log in and, after that, be redirected to an update page. Is that right?

Comment: yes!!! Exactly!!! User logs in and update his details.. this is the exact scenario..Could you help me now @Paulinho

Comment: If I get it right: after the successful message, you can use the code response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com"); to redirect to google, for instance.

Comment: Prior edit removed repeat of code, if you have the code for the other form please post it

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>
>   //creating connection with the database    Connection 
>  con=DriverManager.getConnection
>               ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EATWO","root","");
> ```

For pool sake, do you believe in pooling objects!?, worse you do not close the `Connection`, neither `Statement`s, neither `ResultSet`s!

> ```
>  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from singer where
>  name='" + name + "'");
> ```

Too dangerous(sql inject), use the `PreparedStement` instead as you did with the rest.

This

```
String duplicate = null;
while(rs.next()){
    duplicate = rs.getString(1);
    }
if(duplicate == null){
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
            ("insert into Singer(name,password,member) values(?,?,?)");
     ps.setString(1, name);
     ps.setString(2, pass);
     ps.setString(3, mem);
     int i=ps.executeUpdate();
       if(i>0){
         out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
       }
    }
```

Could be like this

```
if(!rs.next()){
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
            ("insert into Singer(name,password,member) values(?,?,?)");
     ps.setString(1,name);ps.setString(2,pass);ps.setString(3,mem);
     int i=ps.executeUpdate();
       if(i>0){
         response.redirect("<<update_cgi_path_here>>");return;
       }
}
```

After you successfully register the user, redirect him to update page using `redirect(path:String):void` method, like below

```
response.redirect("/update__info");return;
```

---

**Awesomeness:**
You `select` one record, and then `insert` one record if the first one is not exist!
**`C'mon`** what kinda logic is this!, the whole record insertion(persisting new user) should be done by one external/SQL call.
Your code has very good potential for data-inconsistency(as far as I don't know what is going on in sql data structure) because it's not thread-safe.

---

Just like registration page, you may have a html page which user provide its information, simply get the parameters from request(just like register) and update the user data over back-end data source.
But please first have a database connection pool, use `PreparedStatement` over `Statement`(if you need to set something), have some backend sql function which checks and insert users(rather than multiple calls), believe in closing `Closeables`(simply using `try(<<closeable>>){}`)